# Dask Array.compute() peak memory in Jupyterlab

Tags: memory, jupyter, dask, jupyter-lab, dask-distributed

I am working with dask on a distributed cluster, and I noticed a peak memory consumption when getting the results back to the local process.

My minimal example consists in instanciating the cluster and creating a simple array of ~1.6G with dask.array.arange.

I expected the memory consumption to be around the array size, but I observed a memory peak around 3.2G.

Is there any copy done by Dask during the computation ? Or does Jupyterlab needs to make a copy ?

```
import dask.array
import dask_jobqueue
import distributed

cluster_conf = {
    "cores": 1,
    "log_directory": "/work/scratch/chevrir/dask-workspace",
    "walltime": '06:00:00',
    "memory": "5GB"
}

cluster = dask_jobqueue.PBSCluster(**cluster_conf)
cluster.scale(n=1)
client = distributed.Client(cluster)
client

# 1.6 G in memory
a = dask.array.arange(2e8)

%load_ext memory_profiler
%memit a.compute()
# peak memory: 3219.02 MiB, increment: 3064.36 MiB
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for a minimal example! I was able to reproduce this with a `LocalCluster`. :) -- I'd like to understand what's the size of your actual data, and how much memory does your actual setup have? At the 1.5GB range, I think there's an overhead to using Dask, which might skew the diagnosis.

Comment: I work on a HPC setup, with a local process of 20GB. The jupyterlab, notebook and dask client run on this local process. The dataset I need to compute from Dask takes around 7GB, and adding all the previous variables, the memory should be filled up to 14G. What I see during the ds.compute() is that the memory is indeed stuck at 14G for a while, but then there is a memory spike that crashes my jupyter kernel. I think the first part where the memory is around 14G matches the client getting the data from the workers, whereas the copy mentioned in mdurant answer causes the memory spike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you do `compute()`:

- the graph of your computation is constructued (this is small) and send to the scheduler
- the scheduler gets workers to produce the pieces of the array, which should be a total of about 1.6GB on the workers
- the client constructs an empty array for the output you are asking for, knowing its type and size
- the client receives bunches of bytes across the network or IPC from each worker which has pieces of the output. These are *copied* into the output of the client
- the complete array is returned to you

You can see that the penultimate step here necessarily requires duplication of data. The original bytes buffers may eventually be garbage collected later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is quite clear to me ! Does this mean that if I want to compute() a dataset of 10 G, I need to have at least 20G of memory free on my local process ?

Comment: The guides say "a few times the raw dataset size", especially since you presumably want to *do* something with the data in-process, but the exact limit varies case by case. Computing a big dataset to the client is not typical. Also, it may depend on how many workers you are pulling from.

Comment: I agree with you, getting a big dataset on the client is not very common. I will change my approach by either adding a data sink on the workers or processing the dataset entirely before getting it back on the client.